# UITableView from plist dictionary KEYS, iOS

Tags: ios, nsarray, key, plist, jailbreak

I am attempting to get the name of the custom ringtones in the iTunes directory on a jailbroken iPhone. I can successfully list the custom ringtones, but they re displayed as `HWYH1.m4r`, which is what iTunes renames the files, but I know theres a way to decipher the actual name of the song.

```
    NSMutableDictionary *custDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"/iPhoneOS/private/var/mobile/Media/iTunes_Control/iTunes/Ringtones.plist"];
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [custDict objectForKey:@"Ringtones"];
    NSMutableArray *customRingtone = [[dictionary objectForKey:@"Name"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"name: %@",[customRingtone objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
    cell.textLabel.text = [customRingtone objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

**`dictionary`** is returning:

```
"YBRZ.m4r" =     
{
    GUID = 17A52A505A42D076;
    Name = "Wild West";
    "Total Time" = 5037;
};
```

**`cell.textLabel.text`** is returning: `name: (null)`

Comment: How can I cell.textLabel = Name from the Arrays?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *customRingtone = [[dictionary objectForKey:@"Name"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

That line is totally wrong.  Your `dictionary` object it, in fact, an NSDictionary with keys equal to values like 'YBRZ.m4r'.  You are requesting a value for a key named 'Name', which doesn't exist.  Then, with that returned object, you are sending it a method as if it were an `NSArray`, which it isn't.  And then you expect that to return an `NSArray`.  Again, I don't think it does.  It should be more like this:

```
NSArray *keys = [dictionary allKeys];
id key = [keys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSDictionary *customRingtone = [dictionary objectForKey:key];
NSString *name = [customRingtone objectForKey:@"Name"];
cell.textLabel.text = name;
```

Also note, I'm not using `NSMutableDictionary`s.  If you don't need the dictionary to be mutable, you probably should have a mutable dictionary.